# Active Directory Docker - Windows Authentication Mode

Tags: c#, azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How to connect from windows docker container to Azure Active Directory? My problem: I have to connect to Database (in some server) which take only access as a Windows Authentication Mode but my container is not in domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure gMSA (group managed service account) for that. Please follow the below guides in sequence:

1. [Create gMSAs for Windows containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts)
2. [Configure your app to use a gMSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/gmsa-configure-app)
3. [Run a container with a gMSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/gmsa-run-container)
4. [Orchestrate containers with a gMSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/gmsa-orchestrate-containers)