# Trying to authenticate Azure AAD from docker container

Tags: azure, docker, selenium, authentication, active-directory

I am trying to access my application from the container which works on AD authentication. I have written Automation test cases on Selenium. I have no issues in executing them when I try to run from my local. When it comes to executing same from Linux container, I am facing authentication issues.

This is because the container user has no access to the AD which the application uses for Authentication. I have no issues when I curl URL of any other applications that works on form(using username and password) authentication, which clearly shows that my container is intact with the domain.

Is there any ways to make use of Service accounts either from container or in the selenium automation scripts or please let me know if there are any best practices to overcome this issue.

Other details:
Using Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0. chromedriver version: 87.0.4280.2000
Container: Linux.

**P.S: I have already tried to pass username and password as parameter in the url(http://username:password@url.com) and it didn't work in my case.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a similar kind of requirement discussed in below forum. Please check on gMSA (group managed service account)

[Active Directory Docker - Windows Authentication Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575360/active-directory-docker-windows-authentication-mode)

Comment: I too have gone through some blogs and seems like gMSA is the only option. Thanks bro!